# Web scraper hangs silently while multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm scraping a site that contains a couple dozen base urls that ultimately link to several thousand xml pages that I parse, turn into a Pandas dataframe, and eventually save to a SQLite database.  I multiprocess the download/parsing stages to save time, but the script silently hangs (stops collecting pages or parsing XML) after a certain number of pages (not sure how many; between 100 and 200).

Using the same parser but doing everything sequentially (no multiprocessing) doesn't give any problems, so I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the multiprocessing.  Perhaps creating too many instances of the Parse_url class and clogging memory?

Here's an overview of the process:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///path_to_db')  # sqlalchemy

class Parse_url():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url 
    def __enter__(self):
        return self 
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        return True
    def parse(self):
        # parse xml, return dataframes

def collect_xml_links(start_url):
    # collect and return a list of links to XML pages on this starting URL

def parse_urls(url):
    with Parse_url(url) as parser:
        collection_of_dfs = parser.parse()
    return collection_of_dfs

def write_info_to_sql(result, db_name, engine):
    # write info to SQLite database

start_urls = [url1, url2, url3, ... ] 
with Pool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.map(collect_xml_links, start_urls)  
for urls in results:
    url_list.extend(urls)  # This works and returns urls

for i in range(0, len(url_list), 50): # Chunks of 50 to report progress
    url_list_slice = url_list[i:i+50]
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(parse_urls, url_list_slice) 
    for result in results: 
        write_info_to_sql(result, db_name, engine)
```

When the script hangs, it seems to always do so with a similar number of pages scraped, but I'm not certain if it's exactly the same.  Killing the script gives an unhelpful traceback pointing to the `results = pool.map(parse_urls, url_list_slice)` line.

Is there an obvious issue with my multiprocessing setup?  Is it possible that I'm generating too many instances of the Parse_url class?

Comment: I dont see `collect_xml_links` or `start_urls` defined anywhere...

Comment: Where is the fixes? There still is not `def collect_xml_links` or iterable `start_urls`.

Comment: Guessing that the class instances were accumulating, I added 
`del(result)` after `write_info_to_sql(result, db_name, engine)`. That seems to have fixed the hangs, but I'd like to know if there's a better solution

Comment: There's way too little info here, actually. The code is too far stripped down; it could be that you are using the XML parser in a way that deadlocks. Why is `Parse_url` a context manager? You don't do anything with the context hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second loop, you are creating a `Pool` on every iteration which is less than ideal. Python gc is quite lazy so your software piles up a lot of resources during the iteration.

The `multiprocessing.Pool` has been designed for re-usability so you can create it only once in your script.

```
with Pool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.map(collect_xml_links, start_urls)  
    for urls in results:
        url_list.extend(urls)  # This works and returns urls

    for i in range(0, len(url_list), 50): # Chunks of 50 to report progress
        url_list_slice = url_list[i:i+50]
            results = pool.map(parse_urls, url_list_slice) 
            for result in results: 
                write_info_to_sql(result, db_name, engine)
```

Comment: The Python GC is only concerned with cyclic references; resources are cleared *immediately*, through reference counting. Besides, those resources are created in separate processes, not the main process.

Comment: I used wrong words. The resources I meant are the Pool resources (pipes, threads, map results etc). A fast loop creating and destroying Pools gives the feeling of resources leakage as the threads within the Pool prolong the lifetime of the involved objects. The `join` method is what ensures the logic will wait until all resources are released but the OP is not calling it. Nevertheless, the recommended approach is to create a single `Pool` and using it all along the software lifecycle.

Comment: For what it's worth, following this suggestion stopped the hangs and the scraper now completes the ~5000 XML pages correctly as far as I can see

Comment: Good to know it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this isn't ideal, but it worked.  Assuming that the problem was that the multiprocess was creating too many objects, I added an explicit "del" step like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(url_list), 50): # Chunks of 50 to report progress
url_list_slice = url_list[i:i+50]
with Pool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.map(parse_urls, url_list_slice) 
for result in results: 
    write_info_to_sql(result, db_name, engine)
    del(result)  # explicitly delete the dataframes when done with them
```

I'm not sure why the objects are persisting, since it seems that there are no references left to them so they should be garbage collected. I tried a couple other approaches to remove references to them, such as

```
results = []
```

after the batch had all been written, but there were still hangs using that.